# Open device password change programmatically android

Tags: java, android-studio, security

How can I programmatically open the Change Password Screen under Settings -> Security -> Choose screen lock -> Password.

Right now I am using the following code and its getting me as far as Settings -> Security -> Choose screen lock, but I want to force the Password option. Not swipe or pin option.

```
R.id.change_phone_password:
Intent change = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
startActivity(change);
```

I am running Android 10.

Comment: Me myself, I doubt they'd let you do this. It could potentially open up scenarios where people think they are setting a new password but in reality it is also being stolen by the app.

Comment: Enforcing a device password should be done using the [Device administration API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin). If your app is registered as device admin app you can set this policy and the system will force the user to set a password.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the "setPasswordQuality" API of the android DevicePolicyManager. You app has to be registered as a device admin app in order for it to use this API. This API will let you specify password quality as something, numeric, alphanumeric etc. You can also look at other APIs like "setPasswordMinimumLength", "setPasswordHistoryLength", "setPasswordMinimumUpperCase" for more control over what type/length of password you want your endusers to use. All this is only possible if you app is a device admin app.